# Show Customers who used and did not use a specific Transaction type of a channel in a period

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am not sure this falls under what category but i will try to describe my situation and hopefully someone can guide me to where i should be reading and investigating to find a solution.

I will simplify the Design to give an idea about the scenario

we have a Transactions Table

```
Table 1
| Transactions Table |
-------------------------
| Transaction ID     |
| Year               |
| Month              |
| Channel            |
| Transaction Type   |
| CustomerID         | 

Table 2
| Customer        |
--------------
| CustomerID      |
| Name            |
| More details .. |

Now in table 1, i have data in the following format

| Transaction ID | Year | Month | Channel | Transaction Type | CustomerID | 
|----------------|------|-------|---------|------------------|------------|
| 1              | 2017 | 2     | 1       |  Deposit         |  c1        |     
| 1              | 2017 | 2     | 1       |  Inquiry         |  c1        | 
| 1              | 2017 | 2     | 1       |  Withdraw        |  c1        | 
| 1              | 2017 | 2     | 2       |  Deposit         |  c2        | 
| 1              | 2017 | 2     | 1       |  Deposit         |  c2        | 
|----------------|------|-------|---------|------------------|------------|
```

Now the questions i want to answer
- How many customers have used specific channel and transaction in Year 2017 month 2, and how many have not used that transaction type and in which channels.

Its more like flagging things where i can know who used and who didn't use a specific transaction in a specific month.

so the report should look like
- 2 customers Have used Channel 1, in Year 2017 month 1
- out of total 2 customers we have, 1 have user channel 2, and 1 user have not used it.

i hope its clear.

thanks and very much appreciate any support

Regards

Comment: In Excel, you can probably get the information from a pivot table.  Then use various text manipulation techniques to put together those sentences.  Edit your post when you have tried something, and run into problems and have a question.  Or provide an answer if you develop a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Hi, sorry i think i might have gave wrong idea of what i want, i am not looking for sentences, just normal numbers in a table, and the thing with excel is it cant handle large data, in this case i am talking about 100s of 1000s of records

Comment: If you are not looking for an Excel solution, then you should remove the Excel tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found some inaccuracy in your example table1, the one of Transaction, because you have there all 1 as **Transactions' ID**(so I don't understand if it is the number of the transaction placed by a customer, but in this case should be unique, or is referring to a transaction type, but also in this case it should be unique, that could be simply a way to be fast and give us an example, but instead an ID in general is really important in a table, both in a Operational one or a DWH,as is used as reference, so I have recreated your case in a more precise and understandable [way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ba55)

--Transactions issued by your Customer

```
create table  TransactionT
    ( [ID] int,
      [TransactionID] int,
      [Y]    date,
      [Month]     int    ,
      [Channel]    int       ,  
      [Transaction_Type] varchar(10),
      [CustomerID]  int
      )
```

--Customer table

```
create table Customer
(  [CustomerID]  int,   
   [Name]      varchar(10)
)
```

-Transactions Type possible

```
create table  TransactionList
(  [TransactionID] int,
   [Transaction_Type] varchar(10)
)
```

--then inserting some data in those tables

```
insert into Customer(CustomerID,Name )
  values (1,'First'),
         (2,'Second'),
         (3,'Third'),
         (5,'Jay'),
         (6,'PiT'),
         (4,'Marco');


insert into TransactionT (ID,TransactionID,Y,Month,Channel,Transaction_Type, 
CustomerID )
  values (1,1,'2008-11-10',2,4,'Deposit', 2),
         (2,2, '2008-11-11',3,4,'Inquiry', 2),
         (3,3,'2008-11-14',3,4,'Withdraw', 2),
         (4,1,'2017-11-15',3,4,'Deposit', 5), 
         (5,1,'2017-11-16',3,4,'Deposit', 6),
         (6,3,'2017-11-16',4,5,'Withdraw', 6),
         (7,1,'2017-11-16',3,4,'Deposit', 2),
         (8,2,'2017-11-16',5,6,'Inquiry', 5),
         (9,3,'2017-11-18',3,4,'Withdraw', 6),
         (10,1,'2017-11-19',3,4,'Deposit', 3);       

insert into TransactionList(TransactionID,Transaction_Type)
   values (1,'Deposit'),
          (2,'Inquiry'),
          (3,'Withdraw');
```

So to answer your first question(How many customers have used specific channel and transaction in Year 2017 month 2), I have made it more general solution, so suitable for any month, but applying simply a where condition you can have  the filter for a specific month,check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ba55/23):

```
select 
   count (Transaction_Type) as COUNT_TR,
   count (Channel) as COUNT_CN,
   count (C.CustomerID) AS COUNT_CS,
   Transaction_Type,
   Month,
   Channel,
   C.CustomerID 

from 
   TransactionT as T
join Customer as C
   on T.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 

group by Transaction_Type, Channel,month, C.CustomerID
```

Instead your second one,"and how many have not used that transaction type and in which channels." Has some grade of "lacking information", indeed how a customer can have used a channel, if not making a Transaction?
I diveded then the question in 2 steps, to know Customers that did not made any Transaction, and [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d29d7/6) the SQL for SQL Server:

```
select CustomerID from Customer
   except (

   select distinct C.CustomerID from TransactionT C
   left join TransactionT T
   on T.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
)
```

This can be obtained also in this [way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6c4c/1)

Instead if want know those Customers that do not made a particular Transaction Method then that is less intuitive and require a subquery, because SQL Server do not support [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033604/select-not-in-multiple-columns), but logically is using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274637/find-missing-pairs-in-sql).

```
select distinct  C.CustomerID,T.Transaction_Type

from TransactionT T

cross join Customer as C

left join (

  select A.TID as TransactionID,A.T as Transaction_Type ,B.C as CustomerID

from 
( 
 select TransactionID TID,Transaction_Type T, C.CustomerID C

from TransactionT T join Customer C

on T.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
) A  join
 (
select TransactionID TID,Transaction_Type T, C.CustomerID C

from TransactionT T join Customer C

on T.CustomerID = C.CustomerID) B

on A.C = B.C


group by A.TID, A.T, B.C

   ) sub

on  sub.TransactionID = T.TransactionID and sub.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
where sub.TransactionID  is null
```

As you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ba55/22)

Hope this helps